# Sys.argv list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, argv, sys

guys. Can someone explain to me why can't I run this script (for converting a jpg into png) in PyCharm? **I get an error list index out of range**. I have the code and the jpg files in the same directory.
The same error occured when I ran a script to merge some pdf files (the files and the .py script were as well in the same directory).

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image

path = sys.argv[1]
directory = sys.argv[2]

if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
  clean_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
  img = Image.open(f'{path}{filename}')
  img.save(f'{directory}/{clean_name}.png', 'png')
  print('all done!')
```

Comment: Are you making sure pycharm adds command line args?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out:
I had to add my args in my Pycharm .py script using the parameters from "modify run configuration" as in this image:

[image]

I suppose the same solution works for my image converter script.

Comment: Yes which is exactly what is suggested in the duplicate link above. No need to also post an answer. Just mark the question as duplciate